# Using StandardCyborgCocoa add swiftassimp as a local library building for ios on mac m1

Tags: swift, xcode, assimp

I got the git clones of StandardCyborgCocoa and swiftassimp locally on my mac, and installed assimp, a dependency of swift assimp, as homebrew. When I tried to apply swiftassimp as a local package in the StandardCyborgCocoaExample project in Xcode, I got the following error: "dyld[53588]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/assimp/lib/libassimp.5.dylib" error and "Building for iOS, but linking in dylib file (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/assimp/5.2.5/lib/libassimp.dylib) built for macOS" warning.

The libassimp.5.dylib file is in that path that it says it doesn't find,
I tried adding different paths to "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH".

But xcode only finds this path "/opt/homebrew/opt/assimp/lib".

How can I get xcode to read the files in the path?
And is the failure to find the path related to the warning I wrote above?
To resolve the above warning, I need to have the dylib file for ios, but how do I get it?

ps: Ultimately, what I want to do is change the tinyGLTF file to an obj or ply file on iOS.

Comment: Information
'mac m1 ventura 13.2.1
Assimp 5.2.5 (but installed file is 5.2.4)
SwiftAssimp , StandardCyborgCocoa are cloned from git'

tried changing paths:
'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
PKG_CONFIG_LIBS
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES'

tried add paths to xcode build settings

reinstalled:
'Assimp, StandardCyborgCocoa, SwiftAssimp, MacOS'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.